# extracting columns in a sorted multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

How can I get the whole first column of a multidimensional array without using loops. I am trying to pass the first column to another function as an array.
For rows, I only use array[i] and than the i row is passed, but for columns I had to use a temp array and put the elements of the wanted column. 
Is there any easier way that is not in O(n) complexity.
I tried to use array[][0] or anything similar but non of it seems to work.
I am working in java. 
Thank you

Comment: Multidimensional arrays are arrays of arrays, so you have one array, which elements are references to other arrays. That is why you can pass whole row, because you have reference to this array. Columns in the other hand are different references to different arrays, you need to iterate through rows and obtain elements which you want. If you do this multiple times you can store two arrays, one with rows as columns and second in the other way. Then you will have references to rows and colums

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** there is no way for this to be done in less than O(n).

**Explanation:** this is because of the nature of how arrays are represented in Java. In Java, an array is an Object, and as such you can pass it in O(1) through reference. A matrix is an array of arrays, which means every item of each column is a separate item in each array. This means you have to take each individual item in each array object, which makes it at least O(n).

Edit: as Kamil has mentioned in a comment, you could store columns separately, which could then be passed in O(1). Storing takes O(n) in both time and memory.